# Incorrect jacoco coverage while using mockito

Tags: spring, kotlin, mockito, jacoco

My class have a simple method user exist

```
fun userExist(username: String): Boolean {
    return userRepository.userExist(username)
}
```

And a test for this

```
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userService: UserService

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Nested
    inner class UserExistTest{

        @Test
        fun `user exist must return true if user in repository`(){
            Mockito.`when`(userRepository.userExist("user")).thenReturn(true)

            assertEquals(true, userService.userExist("user"))
        }

        @Test
        fun `user exist must return false if user not in repository`(){
            Mockito.`when`(userRepository.userExist("user")).thenReturn(false)

            assertEquals(false, userService.userExist("user"))
        }

    }
```

But when i run test i got 75% coverage(on 1 string lmao), but i think coverage must be 100%

[image]